# How to rationalise the trend in the covalent radii of the transition metals?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, periodic-trends

Why do the covalent radii of transition series decrease at the start rapidly, then become almost constant and at the end of series begin to increase from left to right in periodic table?